# Phase transition from gas to solid

Tags: physical-chemistry, nomenclature, phase

Question 13 from the [ACS chemistry olympiad](http://www.acs.org/content/dam/acsorg/education/students/highschool/olympiad/pastexams/2011-local-olympiad-exam.pdf) exam:

> The phase transition from gas to solid is called 
>   \begin{align}
> &\text{(A) condensation.} & \text{(B) evaporation.} \\ 
> &\text{(C) polymerization.} & \text{(D) sublimation.}
> \end{align}

I am pretty sure the answer is deposition, which is not listed, but yet the answer is (**A**) **condensation** [scroll to the end of the question paper to see the answer key].

Did the chemistry olympiad make a mistake, or is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the diagram of phase changes you have in mind looks like this:

[image]

**Indeed this says *deposition* is the right name for a gas-to-solid phase transition and I believe that this is the only correct term.**

The only thing I can argue why it is obvious here that condensation is the right answer (at least the closest) is that this is the only answer that gives a transition from fluid to solid. B and D are the other way around, and C is not really a phase change (although it could result in one).

Comment: Good point concerning the condensation as the only "real" phase change in a classical sense.